# The proxy configuration is not being applied correctly when deploying your app to Vercel

Tags: proxy, vercel

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy:{
      "/api/v1": "https://myapp.onrender.com",
    }
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

it is my vite.config.js files code ,hear when my frontend app make any api request on `/api/v1/users/login` or any other route then the request URL is converted into `https://myapp.onrender.com/api/v1/users/login`

but when i deploy the frontend app in vercel then the proxy URl is overwrite
then my app make any api request on `"https://myapp.coral.vercel.com/api/v1"` instead of `"https://myapp.onrender.com/api/v1/"` so my app throw 404 not found error.
please tell how can i fixed it?

my app trying to make api requests on `"https://myapp.onrender.com/api/v1/"`
but when i deploy my app on vercel then my app make request on `"myapp.coral.vercel.com/api/v1"`